# Is there a free alternative to Azure Notifications Hub?

Tags: android, push-notification

What is the best and free alternative to Azure Notifications Hub ? I saw there were a lot of them but what would you recommend for Android ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use Firebase Cloud messaging, it's simple and easy to implement

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging